# How to update a field's value based on a match condition for current data and one another?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table `#temp` in sql server 2008 like:

```
Id  p_id  h_id  ProvincialPID
1   100   A1256     null
2   200   A7865     null
3   300   A5555     null
4   100   A1256     null
5   300   A5555     null
6   400   A7865     null
...
```

Please note that for the records `p_id` values are equal, `h_id` values must be equal (check 100 and 300)! On the other hand, there are some record whose `p_id` values are not equal but `h_id` values are equal (like 200 and 400)!

What I want is to update `ProvincialPID` column based on the fact that: if a record's `p_id` is matching another record's `p_id`, then `ProvincialPID = p_id`, else if a record's `p_id` does not match any others but its `h_id` matches at least one other, then `ProvincialPID = h_id`

Example: For the sample data above, I am supposed to see:

```
Id  p_id  h_id  ProvincialPID
1   100   A1256     100
2   200   A7865     A7865
3   300   A5555     300
4   100   A1256     100
5   300   A5555     300
6   400   A7865     A7865
...
```

The code below is helping me to perform it. However, it is extremely slow and I would like to apply a more efficient code. But I could not find a way to make it more efficient. Any help/advice will be so appreciated.

```
DECLARE @counter INT = 0;
DECLARE @currentPID varchar(50);
DECLARE @currentID varchar(50);
DECLARE @currentHID varchar(50);

WHILE @counter < (select COUNT(*) from #temp)
BEGIN
   set @currentID = (select top (1) x.Id from (select top(@counter) * from #temp order by Id desc) x)
   set @currentPID = (select top (1) x.p_id from (select top(@counter) * from #temp order by Id desc) x)
   set @currentHID = (select top (1) x.h_id from (select top(@counter) * from #temp order by Id desc) x)

   if((select COUNT(*) from #temp t where t.Id != @currentID and t.p_id = @currentPID) > 0)
      update #temp 
      set ProvincialPID = @currentPID
      where Id = @currentID
   else if ((select COUNT(*) from #temp t where t.Id != @currentID and t.p_id != @currentPID and t.h_id = @currentHID) > 0)
      update #temp 
      set ProvincialPID = @currentHID
      where Id = @currentID

   SET @counter = @counter + 1;
END;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay first some general advice - if you ever find yourself doing while loops, or using cursors in SQL, you are probably doing it wrong. You almost never need them. Instead think about writing queries to get the set of data you want, and apply the change to the whole set in one go.

Here is what I think you need... works for you example data at least.

```
create table #temp
(
    Id int,
    p_id int,
    h_id varchar(5),
    ProvincialPID varchar(5)
);

insert into #temp(Id, p_id, h_id) values(1,100,'A1256');
insert into #temp(Id, p_id, h_id) values(2,200,'A7865');
insert into #temp(Id, p_id, h_id) values(3,300,'A5555');
insert into #temp(Id, p_id, h_id) values(4,100,'A1256');
insert into #temp(Id, p_id, h_id) values(5,300,'A5555');
insert into #temp(Id, p_id, h_id) values(6,400,'A7865');

update #temp
set ProvincialPID = p_id
where p_id in (select p_id from #temp group by p_id having count(*) > 1)

update #temp
set ProvincialPID = h_id
where p_id not in (select p_id from #temp group by p_id having count(*) > 1)
and h_id in (select h_id from #temp group by h_id having count(*) > 1)

select * from #temp
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do this as two updates, one for `p_id` and one for `h_id`:

```
update t
    set ProvincialPID = p_id
    from #temp t 
    where exists (select 1
                  from #temp t2
                  where t2.p_id = t.p_id and t2.id <> t.id
                 );

update t
    set ProvincialPID = h_id
    from #temp t 
    where exists (select 1
                  from #temp t2
                  where t2.h_id = t.h_id and t2.id <> t.id
                 ) and
          ProvincialPID is NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
;WITH cte AS (
    SELECT
       Id
       ,COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY p_id, h_id) as MatchBothCount
    FROM
       #temp t
)

UPDATE t
    SET ProvincialPID = CASE
                WHEN c.MatchBothCount > 1 THEN CAST(t.p_id AS VARCHAR(5))
                ELSE t.h_id
             END
FROm
    #temp t
    INNER JOIN cte c
    ON t.Id = c.Id
WHERE
    t.ProvincialPID IS NULL
```

Depending on your data you may have some use cases missing such as when a record has no match at all, or 3 records match h_id but only 2 of those 3 match p_id.  Based on that unknown I interpreted as if there is more than 1 record with the same p_id, h_id combination then use the p_id.  If not use h_id.  using a simple count(*) over window function will help you get there.

Or you could use the exists method but still do it in one operation such as:

```
UPDATE t
    SET ProvincialPID = CASE WHEN EXISTS (
                          SELECT 1
                          FROM #temp t2
                          WHERE
                             t.p_id = t2.p_id
                             AND t.h_id = t2.h_id
                             AND t.Id <> t2.Id)
                       THEN CAST(t.p_id AS VARCHAR(5))
                       ELSE t.h_id END
FROM
    #temp t
WHERE
    ProvincialPID IS NULL
```